# Integrated a custom recipe but don't see any changes in rootfs after flashing

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I created a custom recipe which includes some service files to be a part of sysfs, and even though I'm able to build the entire image and flash it, I just don't see any changes in the rootfs.

```
bitbake-layers show-recipes | grep <recipe-name>
// i see the newly added recipe here
```

The following is the `do_install_append()` in the recipe bb file:

```
do_install_append() {
   if ${@bb.utils.contains('DISTRO_FEATURES', 'systemd', 'true', 'false', d)}; then
      install -d ${D}/etc/initscripts
      install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
      mv ${D}/etc/init.d/<daemon_file> ${D}/etc/initscripts/<daemon_file>
      install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/<recipe>/<service_file> ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/<service_file>

      install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/multi-user.target.wants/
      ln -sf ${systemd_unitdir}/system/<service_file>  ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/multi-user.target.wants/<service_file>
  fi
}
```

I go into `/etc/initscripts/` and don't see `<daemon_file>` for instance.

Is there anything else I should be looking into to debug the issue because the build itself runs fine?

Comment: Maybe the flash drive doesn't work correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your recipe.

Here are some points to consider:

- Your `do_install_append` copies the file only if `systemd` is in `DISTRO_FEATURES`.

To make sure of that, check:

```
bitbake -e | grep ^DISTRO_FEATURES=
```

or add `bbwarn "Message"` into your recipe to make sure that the block is executed.

- Make sure to add the files to `FILES_${PN}`:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/initscripts/<daemon_file> \
                ${systemd_unitdir}/system/<service_file> \
                ${systemd_unitdir}/system/multi-user.target.wants/<service_file>"
```

- Check the `${D}` folder of the recipe before building the full image.

```
$ bitbake -e <recipe> | grep ^D=
D=".../tmp/work/.../<recipe>/<version>/image"

$ cd <path>
$ tree .
```

To activate `systemd` use:

```
INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't see `systemd` in `DISTRO_FEATURES`. That's probably causing the block not getting executed hence no install?

Comment: however I see I do see the `Message` in one of the logs...

Comment: So, activate `systemd` as mentioned in my edit

Comment: but the block is being executed no?

Comment: The block gets executed only if `systemd` is in `DISTRO_FEATURES`, I tried your code with `systemd`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually install the package this recipe creates into the image? Just because you bitbake a recipe doesn't mean the contents go into every image, you need to add the package name to `IMAGE_INSTALL` too.

Comment: Yes, I added `IMAGE_INSTALL += "<recipe-name>" in the corresponding .inc file